# Apparently there are no mistakes in my code but still it's not working

Tags: javascript

Here is the code. Please help!
I cannot figure out the error. I've checked it in https://html5.validator.nu/#l4c7 which says my code is correct. however, it's not working in browser.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>practice3</title>
</head>
<body>
<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
var y = "53";
var z = "sugar";
var w =y+ z;
var x = z + y;      
function myFunction() {
return x;
}
document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = myFunction();   
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It works in codepen.com

Comment: The validator validates for valid Html, it does not check whether the JavaScript will do what you expect it to do nor if it is valid.

Comment: Did you got it fixed? Please close the question

Answer (score 1):

Your code works perfectly as you can see in the snippet below. You need to save it as a `.html` file, then it will normally open in your browser.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>practice3</title>
</head>
<body>
<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
  var y = "53";
  var z = "sugar";
  var w =y+ z;
  var x = z + y;      
  function myFunction() {
    return x;
  }
  document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = myFunction();   
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Works fine for me.

I used google Chrome to test it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>practice3</title>
</head>
<body>
<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
var y = "53";
var z = "sugar";
var w =y+ z;
var x = z + y;      
function myFunction() {
return x;
}
document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = myFunction();   
</script>
</body>
</html>
```